# Linking to property values in a Semantic Form

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

I have a Semantic Form, which has several input fields with tokens. These input fields allow the user to pick a range of values from a property. I would like to know how to convert these values from text to links, so that on the resulting MediaWiki page the user could click on the value of a property to navigate to the corresponding SearchByProperty page.

In the Wiki I have (http://idlab.tlu.ee/patterns/index.php/Cross-Device_Drag-and-Drop), for example the values in property Design Motivation would be links, which would take the user to the corresponding SearchByProperty pages, for example this one: http://idlab.tlu.ee/patterns/index.php/Special:SearchByProperty/Design-20motivation/Creating-20technological-20infrastructure

Answer (score 1):

I think the normal way this is accomplished is by using the Template output format. Then in the Design Motivation field you can link to the Search by property page in the template.

The way I would normally have accomplished this is by having the type of the property Design motivation as Page not Text. Then in the Design motivation template I would have an #ask query listing pages using this property. You lose the ability to restrict inputs like that, but in my experience it's pretty easy to catch (often mistakenly) newly created Design motivations.

Comment: Changing the type of the property to Page indeed turns its values into links, however these point to empty pages. Is there a way to make them point to the corresponding search pages?

Comment: http://semantic-mediawiki.org/w/images/f/fc/What's_new_in_Semantic_Forms.pdf#14 shows that there are new mapping options that might help you